# Create object in form angular 2 ionic 2

Tags: json, object, ionic2, angular2-forms

here's the ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SalePage } from "../sale/sale";
import {Md5} from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';
import { DatabaseProvider } from "../../providers/database/database";

@Component(
{
    selector: 'page-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage
{
    sellerData = {Ownership: {Single: "", Double: ""}, Name: {First_Name: "", Last_Name: ""}};
    constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private db: DatabaseProvider)
    {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(SalePage);
    }
    closeApp()
    {
        this.platform.exitApp();
    }
}
```

I want to create a multi dimensional object in ionic form.

Something like that:
`sellerData = {Ownership: {Single: "", Double: ""}, Name: {First_Name: "", Last_Name: ""}};`

How can I create it in form. and use it like this: `[(ngModel)] = "sellerData.Ownership.Single"`

Help me, thanks.

```
<form #sellerData = 'ngForm'>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            <label>Ownership</label>
            <select>
                <option value = "">Select Ownership</option>
                <option value = '1' [(ngModel)] = "sellerData.Ownership.Single" name = "Single" placeholder = "Single">Single</option>
                <option value = '2' [(ngModel)] = "sellerData.Ownership.Double" name = "Double" placeholder = "Double">Double</option>
            </select>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)] = "sellerData.Name.First_Name" name = "First_Name" placeholder = "First name"></ion-input>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)] = "sellerData.Name.Last_Name" name = "Last_Name" placeholder = "Last name"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the issue? are you getting errors with this?

Comment: This is the error: :/ `core.js:1350 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Single' of undefined`

Comment: where are you setting sellerData object? can you show the ts side?

Comment: [edit] the question with the code.. please dont add in comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your select is wrong, you can't bind `ngModel` to an option and also your object is wrong to be used in a select. If you're specting `single` and `double` to be true, false or a number to identify them you just need `ownership` like this:

```
<ion-item>
  <label>Ownership</label>
  <select [(ngModel)]="sellerData.Ownership">
    <option value = '0'>Select Ownership</option>
    <option value = '1' name = "Single" placeholder = "Single">Single</option>
    <option value = '2' name = "Double" placeholder = "Double">Double</option>
  </select>
</ion-item>
```

And your object:

```
sellerData = {Ownership: "", Name: {First_Name: "", Last_Name: ""}};
```

If you're specting `single` and `double` to be a string, you'll need a input for every property like you did in `sellerData.Name.Last_Name`.

Hope this helps.